# CSS: Using different width depending on screen resulution

Tags: html, css

I have following structure of an HTML document:

```
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
<div>

</body>
```

Is it possible to define different width for the `main`, `left`, `center` and `right` depending on the screen resulation. For example if the screen resulution is 1280 or higher, main width should be 1140px. If it is 1280 or lower, the width should 960px?
Thanks.

PS. I understand we can define the width in %, but I am interested to know if we can define 2 different fixed widths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only CSS, you can use media queries. [Here's the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), and [some examples](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/). Note that not all browsers support this feature.

Comment: The spec is part of CSS 2.1. Not that this means much. Current browser support => http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Comment: @Maheep — CSS 3 is normal CSS. Don't get hung up on version numbers, just worry about browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript for this. Jquery can can give better syntax. Use `screen.width` to get the width of user screen and then resize your content accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

this is the javascript you can use to check the screen width and height.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);
</script>
```

reference.. 
http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/browser-screen-resolution/

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved using javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
if ((screen.width>=1024) && (screen.height>=768)) {
  alert('High resolution');
} else {
  alert('Low resolution');
}
</script>
```