# Can I add a function to resize my entire page in HTML?

Tags: html, resize

I'm trying to get a website I am working on to resize for different screen resolutions. It's currently set up for 1080p, but I want it to act like a normal website and resize to any resolution.

I have got all the content and links done, it's literally just the size of the website I want changing.

If anyone could help that would be great, thanks.

Comment: If you want a responsive website you should define your width using percent. You should also take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Using different width depending on screen resulution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801137/css-using-different-width-depending-on-screen-resulution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to make your page adapt to different screen sizes or you can use an existing responsive framework like Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have an example, this link might be helpful for the solution you are trying to achieve (the css style answer in particular):

[Dynamically resize div based on size of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717506/dynamically-resize-div-based-on-size-of-browser-window)